# TRY_CAST is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a puzzle with regards to the behavior of the SQL Server Management Studio.
I am connected to a SQL Server database - version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU3) (KB3094221) - 12.0.4427.24 (X64) 
    Oct 10 2015 17:18:26 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

When I run the following query from management studio, it returns me the correct output.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('ax' AS decimal)

SELECT TRY_CAST('4.0' as decimal)
```

However the built-in editor gives me a message saying this function is not recognized.

[image: Built-In Function]

Edited to Add: Sql Server Management Studio version.
[image: SQL Server Management Studio 2014]

Comment: What compatibility mode is your database set to?  It won't understand the feature if it (the database) is set to anything earlier than `2012`, even if the server is `2014`.

Comment: It looks like it was a SS 2012 function but in 2014 maybe they support it but it isnt part of 2014??

Comment: What version of management studio are you using?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The version is ``12.0.4.100.1``

Comment: @Siyual If that is the case, it should fail to execute the function. the function is getting executed without any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an intellisense error. For some reason MS haven't included try_cast in SSMS 2014, although it's recognised as a valid function in SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 5):

It is available from sql server 2012. Check

```
select @@version
```

Also check the compatibility mode of the database

```
select name, compatibility_level from sys.databases
```

If compatibility mode is less that 110 then make it to >=110 by using alter database

```
alter database yourdatabasename set compatibility_level = 120
```

Comment: The compatibility level of the database is 120.

Answer (score 0):

It's an IntelliSense error which can be solved when it's disabled under the query tab on SSMS 2014